# Bison parse can't tell between variable declaration and assignment

Tags: parsing, bison

So I have rules for my grammar,

```
Method     : METHODNAME Params ')' ':' Types '{' VarsDecs Statements RETURN Returns '}' ';'
           ;
           ;
VarsDecs   : VarDec VarsDecs 
           | 
           ;
VarDec     : VARNAME ':' Types ';'
           ;
Statements : Statement Statements
           |
           ;
Statement  : Assignment
           | Print
           | If
           ;                            
Assignment : VARNAME '=' Expression ';'
           ;
```

And my parser cannot tell when the variable declaration stops and statements start when assignment is the first statement found because assignment also starts with VARNAME.

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that it needs to reduce an empty rule before it can start parsing statements, but when it sees `VARNAME` as the lookahead, it can't tell if its at the end of the variables delcarations yet, as it needs more lookahead to differentiate between a `VarDec` and a `Statement`.

You can improve things a bit by making it left recursive instead of right recursive, but that won't solve the problem completely.  To actually get rid of the problem you need to get rid of the empty statements rule:

```
Statements : Statements Statement
           | Statement
```

and then change the `Method` rule to have two versions, one with statements and one without:

```
Method     : METHODNAME Params ')' ':' Types '{' VarsDecs Statements RETURN Returns '}' ';'
           | METHODNAME Params ')' ':' Types '{' VarsDecs RETURN Returns '}' ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

The grammar isn't all here, so it's hard to test directly, but use of right recursion instead of the [normal left recursion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Recursion.html) may be be part of it.

```
Statements : Statement Statements
VarsDecs   : VarDec VarsDecs
```

try making it left recursive

```
Statements : Statements Statement
VarsDecs   : VarsDecs VarDec
```